Where can the “Did you forget to signal completion?” error come from?
As described in the title, I have the error “Did you forget to signal async completion?”. About my project: I am working on a web part with React that should display a Kudo website.  And now I have this error:

    [11:20:47] Server stopped
[11:20:47] The following tasks did not complete: serve
[11:20:47] Did you forget to signal async completion?
About to exit with code: 0
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!

The problem is that I have not yet found an entry that can help me and since this is my first project, it is very difficult for me to keep track of all the config files.
I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
